# How can i insert my touchEvents.js in another myjs.js file ??? Some examples?

Tags: sencha-touch, extjs

I’m newbuy on Sencha framework. I read the partial guidebook which I have found on the website to try to create some panels with tabs and buttons.
I would like to be able to understand how to create a my “events.js file” where putting the touch gesture event and calling them back into a mean myJS.js file. Particularly, in “dockeditems” which I have created for my mean panel, I have declared a tabPanel, some buttons and a panel where I have specified, as ‘html’, a .svg design file containing a planimetry. I wish I could apply ONLY on this last panel, containing this planimetry (for scaling by fingers), the TOUCH gesture events as PINCH, TAP, etc… How can I do this ?
Could you let me see a very simple example of the way to use a touchEvent.js file (which I have to implement) and how to connect it to the mean file containing the EXT.SETUP( …. onReady…..) ?
Something like that:

(myEventTouch.js)

```
myHandler = function() {“Pinching”};
```

(myPrincipalFile.js)

```
Ext.setup ({ onReady: function(){
new Ext.panel({ dockeditems: myitems })
} 
var dockedItems = [{

xtype: 'toolbar',

title: 'Planimetry',

ui: 'dark',

dock: 'top',

items: “ some buttons “,

},
{
id:'html',
dock:'left',
width: '75%',
// HERE THERE IS THE CRITICAL POINT
html: '<object data="planimetry.svg" style="width: 100%; height: 100%" type="image/svg+xml" id="plan"/>',
handler: myHandler // HERE I WISH CALL BACK MY HANDLER
},
{
dock:'right',
width:'25%',
xtype:'tabpanel',
items: [“something”]
})
```

Thanks in advance :)

p.s.

sorry for my english (i'm italian :P)

Comment: This video is fantastic : http://vimeo.com/17414405
But now, the REAL question is....
How can i add an eventHandler on an HTML's element ?!
Can i call back the SVG's ID ? Listener, that i have created by that video, responds only on panel, not on the svg too :'(